# VBscript - Excel cannot find the value if it comes from a variable

Tags: excel, vbscript

My vbs script is to search excel columns to find the date 7 days from today. then it searches the rows for values ​​and does some action.

below is the main part of the script that should work:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)
Set ActiveSheet = objWorkbook.sheets(1)

Dim row, column, totalrows, totalcolumns
totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalcolumns = 53

newdate = DateAdd("d",7,Now())
ndate = Day(newdate) & "." & Month(newdate) & "." & Year(newdate)


For column = 2 To totalcolumns
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, column).Value = ndate then
        For row = 4 to totalrows
            If not ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = "" then
                
                'Do something
                'Do something

            End If
        next
    End If
next
```

but the problem is the value of the ndate variable.

If I execute this script, it does not find the date in Excel and I know it is looking for the correct date.

So I took it a step further and even when I set the date myself. script doesn't work:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)
Set ActiveSheet = objWorkbook.sheets(1)

Dim row, column, totalrows, totalcolumns
totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalcolumns = 53


ndate = "28.10.2020"


For column = 2 To totalcolumns
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, column).Value = ndate then
        For row = 4 to totalrows
            If not ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = "" then
                
                'Do something
                'Do something

            End If
        next
    End If
next
```

but if I set the date directly like below the script works and finds the date in excel:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)
Set ActiveSheet = objWorkbook.sheets(1)

Dim row, column, totalrows, totalcolumns
totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
totalcolumns = 53


For column = 2 To totalcolumns
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, column).Value = "28.10.2020" then
        For row = 4 to totalrows
            If not ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = "" then
                
                'Do something
                'Do something

            End If
        next
    End If
next
```

Comment: `"28.10.2020"` is a string, not a date. If you compare it to a date, Excel/VBA tries to convert it, but that might or might not work as you expect. What is the content of your cells, a string (that might look like a date) or a date?

Comment: my excel cells are formatted as date. but in this case why does it work when i use:

`If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, column).Value = "28.10.2020" then`

Comment: The `Format` of a cell doesn't say anything about it's content. You can enter "Hello world" into a cell that's formatted as date - that doesn't make it a date.

Comment: so the contetn i see is exactly as i wrote above: `28.10.2020`

Comment: When you format the cell as long date: Does it display the the name of the day and month?

Comment: Yes it is, and when i change it to `General`  it is displayed as `44132`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it comes to *dates*, you need to deal with *dates*. In your code, you are comparing a string with a date:

```
newdate = DateAdd("d",7,Now()) 
ndate = Day(newdate) & "." & Month(newdate) & "." & Year(newdate)
```

Now `newdate` will hold a Date, including a time part. `ndate`, however, contains a String that looks like a date (for some parts of the world).

What you are doing in your code is to compare a String with a Date (which is, in fact, a number as you can see when you format the cell as `General`). When it comes to something like this, the world of programming is divided: While most programming languages wouldn't allow that (throwing an error either at compile- or runtime), some try to do something meaningfull. That would mean that one of the two values needs to be converted, either the string is converted into a date or the date is converted into a string.

The converting *might* work correctly, but it also might fail (because of all the different ways to write a date). When coding, you should avoid those implicit conversions but work with the correct data types. That starts with declaring the variable with the correct type.

In your case, just use

```
Dim ndate
ndate = Dateadd("d", 7, Date())
```

`Date()` is the equivalent to `Now()`, but just with the date-part (without time)

Comment: I understand what's going on but remember it's still VBscript and not VBA, I'm not sure if I can use the declaration `Dim ndate as Date`

Comment: If this is `VBScript`, how can you have something like `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)
Set ActiveSheet = objWorkbook.sheets(1)`

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.  In that case you can't declare the variable as `Date`. But the `DateAdd`-function returns a `Date` and that should do the trick anyhow.

Comment: You're right it looks like the date is automatically recognized so all I had to do was use
`ndate = DateAdd ("d", 7, Date ())`

Comment: You shouldn't need to that if the user regional settings in the OS are set `dd.mm.yyyy` as `CDate()` will use the system settings when converting strings to dates.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are tricky.

- Excel does not have a Date datatype, but VBA does
- Excel stores dates as numbers, and displays a date using formatting.
- The reason your manually entered date in your third example works is because somehow the engine is converting your string to an equivalent date.
- Your first example would work if you were comparing the `.Text` property of the cell, rather than the `.Value` property (and the row is sized large enough to display it.
- A more robust method, when dealing with date, is to use the [`Range.Value2` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144217);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue), as it will be unformatted.

For example:

```
ndate = CDbl(#10/28/2010#) 'or any other method of generating the date and converting it to Double, or Long

For Column = 2 To totalcolumns
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Column).Value2 = ndate Then
        For Row = 4 To totalrows
            If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value = "" Then
                
                'Do something
                'Do something

            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This works great for your example, but what if I want to generate this date?
`newdate = DateAdd("d",7,Now())`
`ndate0 = "#" & Day(newdate) & "/"& Month(newdate) & "/" & Year(newdate) & "#"`
`ndate1 = CDbl(ndate0)`

Comment: @luke00500 The principle demonstrated is that you need to generate a "real date" and convert it to a double.  So something like `newdate = CDbl(DateAdd("d",7,Date))` or, even simpler `newDate = CDbl(Date + 7)`  *(Using `Now` vs `Date` is the difference between including or not including a time component.  If you are not comparing times, then don't use them)*

Comment: There's actually no difference VBA stores Dates as numbers as well, in fact, I'm pretty sure it's VBAs implementation that Excel uses under the covers.

Comment: @Lankymart It is true that they are both stored as double-precision numbers. Not sure that is enough to call them "the same".  Certainly, dates prior to 1-Mar-1900 are stored as different values; and VBA can store dates back to 1-Jan-100;  Excel also has a designed-in flaw where it accepts `29-Feb-1900` as a valid date. The published documentation I have seen describes only four data types for Excel (string, number, boolean and error).